# Чтение из потока в массив байт, не всегда заполняется массив

Tags: winapi, delphi, потоки-данных

Прошу прощения за название, не смог менее сумбурно. Исправите - спасибо)
Ситуация такая. Есть Delphi7, есть array[1..16000] of char и есть поток stdout консольного (через CreateProcess) приложения.
Код:

```
function readOutPart(var Buffer: array of char; hOutput:THANDLE):boolean;
var BytesReadNow, BytesReadTotal: Cardinal;
  rdSuccess: LongBool;
  n: integer;
begin
BytesReadTotal := 0;
BytesReadNow := 0;
BuffSize := 16000;

repeat
  WaitForInputIdle(hOutput, 100);
  rdSuccess := ReadFile(hOutput, Buffer[BytesReadTotal+1], BuffSize-BytesReadTotal, BytesReadNow, nil);
  inc(BytesReadTotal, BytesReadNow);
until ((BytesReadTotal+1 > BuffSize) OR (not rdSuccess));

Result := (BytesReadTotal+1 > BuffSize);
if not Result then
  for n := BytesReadTotal+1 to BuffSize do
    Buffer[n] := #0;
end;
```

И есть плавающая ошибка. Периодически последние (видимо, 100-2000) байт недописываются в массив (остаются предыдущие). Дампить массив "чтоб посмотреть" смысла нет - это куски байтового потока (дискретизация аналогового), соответственно на вид не замечу, где сбой.

Вывод с консоли правильный - вывод в файл/чтение из файла говорят, что все нормально, но нужен реалтайм. А реалтайме помехи. Возникает ошибка где-то в 2-3% проходов функций (при этом она возвращает true, т.е. читается ровно 16000 байт).

Да, это звук. Помехи выражаются в окончании текущего блока концом предыдущего.

ЗЫ: цикл сделан, потому как консоль выдает 8192 байта и ждет, пока их прочитают.
ЗЗЫ: иногда вместо наслоения получается хрип/визг. Такое чувство, что некоторые куски читаются не из потока, а из какого-то рандомного куска памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте перед повторным использованием сделать 
fillchar или zeromemory (вроде правильно названия функций написал )

Comment: Пишите в ответ, зачту)) Помогло отладить. Кстати, не подскажете, почти при передаче по ссылке array[1..16000] of char запись в первый символ выглядит Buffer[0] := { value } ?)